# I want to write an ELF file by hand.How could I make my elf file call the c standard library

Tags: assembly, linker, x86-64, elf

I want to write an ELF file by hand.How could I make my elf file call the c standard library. I know about the kernel search for the PT_INTERP program header and read "/lib/ld-linux.so.2", and I know about Global Offset Table(GOT) and  Procedure Linkage Table(PLT).

But I don not know how an ELF file with PT_INTERP phdr, GOT, PLT get executed and call C library. I need to know it in binary to help me create a handmade ELF.

Comment: Just create one with compiler & linker and investigate its structure.

Comment: _I want to do it myself_ "just get someone else to do it, and look at what they did"

Answer (score 0):

[What happens is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826380/i-want-to-write-an-elf-file-by-hand-how-could-i-make-my-elf-file-call-the-c-stan):

1. the kernel maps the main executable and dynamic linker in the process VAS (virtual address space);
2. the kernel starts the execution of the process by context-switching to the dynamic linker entry point;
3. the dynamic linker maps the references (`DT_NEEDED`) shared-objects in the process VAS

   - you need to add a `DT_NEEDED` entry for the `libc` if you want to use it
4. the dynamic linker do the relocations:

   - you need a GOT entry for your `libc` function;
   - you need a PLT entry for your `libc` function (and the special `.PLT0` entry) which use this GOT entry;
   - you need a relocation entry for fixing up the GOT entry;
   - the relocation entry needs to reference an entry for the `libc` funtion in the (dynamic) symbol table;
   - you need to setup the `DT_RELA`, `DT_REL`, `DT_RELASZ`, `DT_RELSZ`, `DT_RELAENT`, `DT_RELENT`, `DL_PLTREL`, `PLTRELSZ`, `DT_JMPREL` accordingly;
   - your code can call the PLT entry.
5. the dynamic linker calls your executable entry point.

Comment: I saw this [link](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/somewhat.html).He didn't use any GOT or PLT.And ran well.But when I import to 64bit C ,a segment fault came.How the relocation runs when there is no GOT or PLT.PS  the relocation type is still R_386_PC32.

Comment: @yuantf: "when I import to 64bit C"?

Comment: I write a C program.This program creates x64 ELF file based on the article:A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Somewhat Teensy ELF Executables for Linux.To be honest I just translate the asm to C code.@ysdx